# I wiped hard drive on Intel MacBook Air and Recovery Mode doesn't work

Tags: recovery

I have an old MacBook Air from like 2015 and the screen is broken, so I bought a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter and it worked so I wiped the hard drive but now I can't enter Recovery Mode what do I do.

Comment: What exactly is happening?  How did you wipe the drive in the first place?

Comment: I entered Recovery Mode with Command-R and opened up Disk Utility and Erased something called "MacOS Base System" iirc

Comment: And what is happening **now**?

Comment: It turns on but there is no boot sound or video output from the Thunderbolt port

Comment: Are you holding `Opt-Cmd-R`?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem like there is any video output still (also there is a boot sound I remembered incorrectly)

Comment: You should have a boot chime.  Reset the NVRAM  - `Option-Command-P-R`, then run Diagnostics by holding `D` while booting

Comment: there was a boot chime i remembered incorrectly but i don't see video output from the diagnostics thing

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac? If so, boot into [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-mide/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac). This way you can install macOS onto the drive of the broken Mac using the keyboard and display of the good one

Comment: my other mac which im using right now is an m2 mac would it work

Comment: Try.  The worst that can happen is it won’t work.

Comment: the apple website says i need to use the thunderbolt cable is the os is macos 11 or newer but there isn't an os installed so what do i do

Comment: get a TB cable.  It’s what’s required

Comment: ok ill get one when i can